# Conflicts in gms/firebase libraries in android gradle dependencies

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have a conflict in `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1`.

The error I am getting is:

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.0.4, 15.0.1, 15.0.0. Examples include com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1 and com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0 more... (Ctrl+F1)

This is my gradle settings:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.8.0'

implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
}
// Firebase plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

More information:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.home.radio'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 49
    versionName "2.4.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

More informations:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I downloaded a project from firebase website, and i found exactly the same problem, i think the problem is from firebase end.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I just updated everything to the latest versions, using sdkcompileversion 28.0.0, i also removed the admobe ads library, and used firebase ads. This link helped me too https://firebase.google.com/docs/ad

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using most suitable versions(not necessary the same version number)- read this
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

```
//like this(for example)
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I did that, I followed this website and updated them, yet same problem, I edited my code above as well.
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases

Answer (score 0):

Add explicitly the library with the old version but with a new version number.
And: don't forget to press sync now so gradle can rebuild the dependency graph and see if there are any more conflicts.

For your case, you can try change:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Comment: Hello, I edited my Code, I updated everything to a newer version, yet same problem.

Comment: You add follow recomment from Android studio. Add com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0

Comment: I added implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1' and the first conflict is gone, thanks, now I still have a conflict in implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1' , when I remove all the firebase dependencies the red line goes away, so i am sure it has to do with firebase

Comment: about add firebase, you can follow at https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup. This post help you setting file gradle

Comment: I already did that, I had firebase 12.0.0, when I upgraded everything to the newest dependency that was when conflicts started showing. I will remove firebase and install let the wizard install it again..hope that fixes it.